# android: Can I create multiple AdMob ADs for a single Android app?

Tags: android, admob

- I want to publish my app with different sites(ADs) and want keep track the
  earnings of each of them.
- Can I use multiple ID's for a single app?
- I can't find anything related 
  in the help page.
- I am new to android development.

Comment: You can place the multiple ads in different-different activities of your application using the single ID or multiple IDs as well.

Comment: thank you, for getting multiple ID what should i do?                 can i put multiple ads in one activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create and use more than one mediation id for a single app.

Create them at https://mediation.admob.com/#manage:mediation/create and just give them different names. You will either need to have 2 versions of your app, one for each each deployment site with its own mediation id, or a single version of your app that uses some form of configuration to choose the appropriate meidation id.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the developer guide for the `AdMobs` by referring the link [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation)

It will guide you to generate the multiple ids for the ads and how to integrate the ads in your application.

Comment: I tried to generate 2nd mediation id but it show message "you have already used this app name/package." so, it doesn't generate ID 2nd time for new AD.

Comment: so you got your answer now. You can not use two ids for multiple admobs in your application. :)